# I want a modal pop up form calling another page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, popup, bootstrap-modal, cakephp-3.0

im using cakephp 3.4.13 and  bootstrap version below

register.ctp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
          <h4>Modal Example with inline form</h4>
          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal">

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Job</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                    </form>    
                </div>


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

above code will pop up if Im on the register.ctp because the button is also in present in the page,   My problem is how to make this form available if Im on the other page.

I would like to call this on login.ctp

using anchor tag

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Register',array('controller' =>'users','action' => 'register'),array('data-target'=>'#myModal','data-toggle'=>'modal')); ?>
```

Comment: Save this block of code as the element, then include the element file where ever you want and create a button to do the same

Comment: @bikash.bilz  I solved it by putting the bootstrap in register.ctp

Comment: @bikash.bilz  do you have idea? how to call 2 remote data url... I have 2 link in login.ctp  which is register button and forgotpassword button I want this two buttons when click to pop up, but i cant make it only the register button working.

Comment: Didn't get your point, Does popup appear on both button click? Do you connect to the remote URL using AJAX?

Comment: please see link  when I click register button it shows pop up but sometimes forgot password will pop up i interchange the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69fb65cd6bfb488e43d7c4fb399c7c99

Comment: I just use modal ,, all the codes in javascript I try to follow some answers in stackoverflow and i commented now only register button is functioning